# Applying algorithms to data before its stored in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get information through crowd sourcing and there are some algorithms I want to apply to that data before it's stored into firebase. How can I do this? What firebase services can I use? Thank you in advance

Comment: Remember that *asking us to recommend/find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. Can you provide a clear use case (define your algorithm)? Maybe provide some sample code or perhaps tell us what you've tried so far? You may want to include your Firebase Structure (or desired structure) so we know what the expected result is? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This should be done through a Cloud Function.

You can find a good example in the Firebase official samples:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/text-moderation/functions

This sample shows how a new entry in the database is modified by a "text-moderation" algorithm.

Note that you could have another approach where you read the incoming data in one database node and write the modified data in another node (instead of replacing the original data as shown in this sample).

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the question; the OP wants to run algorithms on the data *before* it's stored in Firebase, suggesting to use Cloud Functions would work on the data *after* it's already been written (or as it's writing). This is a crowd sourcing project so there could literally be millions of data sets; suppose the algorithm is to 'filter' that data so all of the data sets don't have to be written - that would need to be performed before the data get's to the Firebase server.

Comment: @Jay I get your point. However there isn't a lot of possibilities: manipulating the data before it is written can only be done in the client, which means that algorithm's code shall be public (i.e. expose in the client side code if it's a web app). If on the other hand the OP wants to protect its "secret sauce" (i.e. the algorithm) I don't think there are many other possibilities than the one I've proposed. And I also note the OP asked for "Firebase Services" which makes me to thinking the OP doesn't want to implement the algorithm in the client side.